# Angular 2 webpack load external libraries

Tags: angular, typescript

I am loading Wistia (a video embed service) in my application. The script code has to be embedded in the main `index.html` file so that it works where i use their embed code. Is there a way to call it in just specific components? The script loads slowly and the entire app lags until its loaded up.

Also - is there a way to make it like a function, perhaps something like `loadWistia()` that i can include in my components where its needed. If so, will this be part of a shared NgModule which is loaded everywhere and are there any performance impacts because of the shared NgModule bloating up with such scripts in the long run?

**EDIT index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>System</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300italic,400,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Wistia embed script -->
    <script charset="ISO-8859-1" src="//fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js" async></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
    </body>
</html>
```

*HTML where its embedded*

```
<div class="wistia_embed wistia_async_j38ihh83m5 embed-responsive-item">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Please provide the `index.html` and a sample code/component where you use the script.

Comment: I have added `index.html` containing the `<script>` tag for wistia which i want to get rid of. In order to embed a video you need to use a tag as in my post.